# Firebase Call running last in ViewDidLoad

Tags: swift, firebase, swift4, viewdidload

I have a view controller in which I want to make a firebase pull, and then I want to push the data from the firebase pull into a "DataController" that transforms the data so it fits into the UITableViewDelegate. The problem is that there are four DataControllers, and a segmented control selects which of them is being used.

How do I make it so that the firebase function runs first in ViewDidLoad() and I can pass a value into the DataController.

Relevant lines of code are below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var contactData: ContactData!
    private var dataControllers: [DataController] = [
        DataController1(data:contactData),
        // this is where am setting the DataController init data currently, but I have to let firebase run first
        DataController2(),
        DataController3(),
        DataController4()
    ]
    private var segment: Segment = .profile {
        didSet {
            let dataController = self.dataControllers[self.segment.rawValue]
            self.tableView.dataSource = dataController
            self.tableView.delegate = dataController
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    self.tableView.dataSource = dataController
    self.tableView.delegate = dataController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            FirebaseAPI.shared.getData(contactID: contact.contactID) { [weak self] result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let result):
                        self?.contactData = result
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }

                }
            }
         //.....
     }
```

How would I feed contactData into DataController(data: ContactData)? Right now the firebase code is running last in ViewDidLoad().

Sorry for the basic question, I am still learning Swift and Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create that `DataController` in callback?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var contactData: ContactData!
    var dataController : DataController?
    // this is where am setting the DataController init data currently, but I have to let firebase run first

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            FirebaseAPI.shared.getData(contactID: contact.contactID) { [weak self] result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let result):
                        dataController = DataController(data: result)
                        self.tableView.dataSource = dataController
                        self.tableView.delegate = dataController
                        self.tableView.reloadData();
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }

                }
            }
         //.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, so I guess the part I left out is there are four dataControllers, and depending on the segmented control, that's how the dataController is chosen, I'll update the code to reflect this.

Comment: @user3628240 It seems all of the DataControllers are using the same result data, right? So this answer would be a good option as any of the DataControllers could be instantiated within the switch statement. i.e. just put the decision making process about which controller to use within the closure.